# How to convert to 24 hr format (google app script)

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, time

```
  function dailyEventMessage() {
  var googleCalendarId = "xxxxxx@group.calendar.google.com";

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(googleCalendarId);
  var today = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(),today.getDate()+1);
  var tomorrowEventList = calendar.getEventsForDay(tomorrow);

  const date = new Date(tomorrow) 
  const tomorrowdateresult = date.toLocaleDateString('th-TH', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'long',
 }) 

 var message = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < tomorrowEventList.length; i++) {

  var eventTitle = "Task: "   + tomorrowdateresult + "\n" + "**"+  tomorrowEventList[i].getTitle()+"**";
   var eventTime = "Timebegin: "  + tomorrowEventList[i].getStartTime().toTimeString().slice(0,5)
+"-"+ tomorrowEventList[i].getEndTime().toTimeString().slice(0,5);

  var eventDescription = "Details: "  + tomorrowEventList[i].getDescription();

   message += "\n" + eventTitle + "\n" + eventTime + "\n" + eventDescription + "\n";
 
  }

  if (message === "") {
   return;
  }


  Logger.log(message);
 sendMessage(message);
  }
```

The problem I found is variable eventime, it show on 12 hr format . Ex. 03.00-04.00 but actually time in google calendar I set at 15.00-16.00

Could anyone suggest on how to change it to 24 hr format.
Thks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will be cleaner if you use date formatter. By using `toTimeString()` and `slice(0,5)` your code will broke sometime.

In `Intl.DateTimeFormat` you can set `hour12` config to `false`. It will give you 24-hour format.

```js
const startTime = new Date(2010, 11, 12, 13, 14);
const endTime = new Date(2010, 11, 12, 16, 17);

const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
});

console.log(`${formatter.format(startTime)} - ${formatter.format(endTime)}`);
```

here is some reference: [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)