# Converting time to 24 hours in google script

Tags: time

Cell A1= 05:30 PM

I need to convert this time in google script to a 24 hour clock AND I need to separate out the hours and the minutes.  When I put in the following code...

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Options');
var range = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
var date = new Date(range)
console.log(date)
```

... The result is... Sat Dec 30 1899 18:06:36 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)

IF this were accurate, I know how to parse out the hours and minutes by using .getHours() etc.

HOWEVER, that is not obviously not the accurate time.

Another approach I've used...

```
var time = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()), ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "hh:mm a");
  console.log(time)
```

This result is ... "05:30 PM"

While this is great, it's not in a 24 hour format, and unfortunately, .getHours() and .getMinutes() doesn't work for me.

Ultimately I am looking for a result like this...

var hours = 17
var minutes = 30

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert to 24 hr format (google app script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421841/how-to-convert-to-24-hr-format-google-app-script)

Comment: I don't believe so

Comment: After `a=new Date()`, you can get the hours using `a.getHours()`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

Comment: My problem is the new Date is giving an erroneous time.  See above. This... Sat Dec 30 1899 18:06:36 GMT-0600 ... is not equal to 05:30 p.m.  "18:06:36" is 06:06:36.  No idea why its interpreting 5:30 pm as that.

Comment: I'm guessing a regex expression would work(all numbers before : = hours, and all numbers after colon = minutes), but I have no idea how to write that code. :/

Comment: Please stop guessing, and tell tell us what the value is in cell "A1", something like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsZlW.png (with in cell B1 the function "`=HOUR(A1)`"

Comment: First line of my OP states "cell A1 = `05:30 PM`"

Comment: @Luuk https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w2LAtd1Qd35ah-W1QWAVCaRdS1NXNIDEJivV0TXyri8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the functions: `ISNUMBER(A1)` and `ISDATE(A1)` both return `TRUE` ?

Comment: Correct.  Made you an editor.  Look at the apps script and run my function

Comment: I added a function called "thisWorks()". It has to do with regex comment I made above. I know NOTHING about regex. I just did several google searches to piece some info together.  Ultimately this works and gets the desired result.  I'm just guessing there has to be an easier, more concise way?

Comment: When I use the function `NU()`  (`NOW` in Dutch) I do see then time: `2/20/2024 11:06`, and my localtime is `18:06`  so, Google is doing something with timezones....